# Random socket.io requests in Express application

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

After installing express-session and configuring I've noticed that there have been random socket.io requests coming through, which look like this: `/socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1609776472267-4570`

I've searched all over the code, reviewed the node_modules folder and commented out packages that I was suspicious of being the reason for the requests, but overall no luck.

My Express application was generated through the Express Generator package.

Full request: `GET /socket.io/?X_LOCAL_SECURITY_COOKIE=&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1609776633844-4642 404 0.704 ms - 12`[image: Dependencies]

Comment: How does your API look like? Are u using POSTMAN? More info,please.

Comment: @RichardRublev I used the Postman application to test POST requests, but even after I generated the app, as far as I remember it still sent the socket.io requests. My API mostly consists of GET & POST requests which return data from the database.

Comment: if i remember correct this is just a heatbeat `req` hint is in the `=polling&t=` but suggests its reverting to polling.. Which might be your real issue - How are you connecting to your socket ?

Comment: @Pogrindis I'm not using socket.io in my application & I don't even have it installed, but the requests are still there

Comment: I see, well then what kind of application is this ?  electron for example ? Do you have any debuggers attatched ? Whats the source of the socket call ?

Comment: @Pogrindis Express application (website). I'm using morgan to find out the requests, Express's Generator also supplied some other debuggers but morgan is the one I'm familiar with. I'm clueless on the source of the socket calls, socket.io is not referenced anywhere in the code nor is it in the node_modules folder.

Comment: In your chrome network tab, there is a filter for "WS" check that out, on the right side you'll see the source script at least. Lets see where its sitting - some dependancy is using it/debugger, probably the express-session/cookie-parser/connect-session-lite.. Its using the polling from it though. It's hard to debug without running it.

Comment: Nothing in there, the requests instantly appear in the console after I run "npm run start", I've also tried commenting out the dependencies (express-session & cookie-parser), the requests still persisted.

Comment: Hmm not sure actually. Please try `npm-remote-ls` to check your deps, I cant right now